# How to compare input number by the user with the data from the imported file?

Tags: file, input, compare, python-3.5

I am importing a file with the data and converting that to matrix form from where I want to ask the user to input a number which then will be compare with the numbers in the data and print how many numbers are greater than the input number. But I am keep on getting the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Main User/Documents/University work/Engineering Programming and design/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    if x > i:
TypeError: unorderable types: float() > list()
```

Code:

```
f = open('results.txt', 'r')
row=[]
for line in f:
    row.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
print('test_data')
print(row)
f.close

counter=0
x=float(input("Enter a number"))
for i in row:
    if x > i:
        counter=counter+1

print(counter)
```

Comment: I would avoid mentioning you need help with an assignment, and that you need it as soon as possible. People don't want to do your homework for you, and they especially don't want to feel rushed about doing it. They  will assume you simply procrastinated (even if you didn't). This tends to rub people the wrong way and will get your question more negative attention than positive.

Comment: thanks @esstrada , i will keep that in mind, its just that i am new here, so i didn't knew. thank you for your help, i really appreciated :)

Comment: No problem. Stack Overflow can be a great community to be a part of, but like any community, there are rules of etiquette. It can be hard at first when you don't know those rules yet. Here is a very good article about how to ask question on forums like stack overflow: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html . This article helped me a lot when I was first starting to use SO.

Comment: @esstrada thanks for sharing that link, it help a lot, I understand the rules much better now...

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes it is dealing with just a flat `list` of numbers. What you *actually* have is a `list` of `list`s of numbers. Your second `for` loop needs to be nested. Something like this:

```
for line in row:
    for number in line:
        if x > number:
            counter = counter + 1
```

Or you need to use `extend`, not `append`, like this:

```
for line in f:
    row.extend([float(x) for x in line.split()])
```

This will instead give you a flat list of numbers like your code is expecting.

Comment: i tired using the first code you gave me but it's not really working the way i wanted to, its print numbers like this

Comment: @AbrarSajjad The second bit of code is probably better for your needs anyway. I would try to use that instead. That way you are only dealing with a flat list (which is easier to work with), instead of a nested list.

Comment: @esstrada sorry i didn't realize my comment was not fully posted, the first code you gave me kind of work and it printed 1,2,3,4,5 till 92 when i input number 12.. but what i wanted was the code to print greater value than the number it has been input from the matrix list. plus i tried converting the matrix format into simple list using your second given code but it print out the same as first code you gave...

Comment: It sounds like you need to put a `print` call inside your counter `for` loop, if I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: @esstrada i can not really do that because this code will be in the one menu from where when this option is selected by the user then it should print out the greater values.  i  was trying to define this code as a function so whenever this option is selected by the user, then it will call the function and print. however its still giving me and error